# ParseObject as a data to the table/chart

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm new in coding and I have a problem to understand something. I follow the example form Parse.com Doc and wrote this.

```
public void getData() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseClass");
    query.getInBackground("lxFzCTeOcl", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {    
            if (e == null) {
                String object = parseObject.getString("value");
                int object_value = Integer.parseInt(obiect);
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I understand this like:

- I send query to server
- get obiect with "lxFzCTeOcl" id
- if there is no exception I create String object which takes string
  form "value" column.
- convert String to int

My question is: How can I use object_value for example to make a chart or put it into a table?

Comment: When you say "put it into a table" are you talking about a SQLite table or just a map?

Comment: Just a map. At this moment;)

Comment: A map can be see as a table with two colums <key,value> in your code we only have one value, if you only have one value the best object in this case will be a ArrayList

Comment: I'll try with ArrayList. If you have good and simple example to understand how works ArrayList it would be nice to send it to me. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we will add the array list to your code and start to store an object inside the array every time we call the getData method in your class.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> dataArray;

public void getData() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseClass");
    query.getInBackground("lxFzCTeOcl", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {    
            if (e == null) {
                String object = parseObject.getString("value");
                Integer objectValue = Integer.parseInt(obiect);
                if(dataArray==null)
                    dataArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                dataArray.add(objectValue);
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And here I'm just adding a simple example of how to create a simple pie chart using our array list (note that I used the lib AChartEngine http://www.achartengine.org/):

```
private static int[] COLORS = new int[] { Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE,Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN }; 

private GraphicalView createPieChart(ArrayList<Integer> data){
    GraphicalView chartView;
    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("PIE");

    for (int i = 0; i < VALUES.length; i++) {  
        series.add(i, data.get(i));  
        SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();  
        renderer.setColor(COLORS[(series.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS.length]);  
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);  
    } 

    chartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, series, new DefaultRenderer());
    chartView.repaint();
    return chartView;
}
```

Now you can add this GraphicalView to your view.

Answer (score 0):

The returned object is much like a map, with key/value pairs. In your example, the key is "value", which makes it a little confusing, but it would be like this if you wanted all fields:

```
for (Field field : myInstance.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    String name = field.getName();
    value = field.get(myInstance).toString();
    map.put(name, value);
}
```